# Getting globally most viewed videos with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, api, search, video, filter

I want to use the Facebook Graph API to generate lists of the most-viewed videos within certain filters, like under a certain lengh, uploaded in the past month, etc. I know that I can get this data from individual videos, but I want to perform a search on all of Facebook for videos that fit these criteria.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> but I want to perform a search on all of Facebook for videos that fit these criteria.
>
> Is there any way to do this?

No, there is not.

You can not access “all videos”, you always need to go via a specific profile or page first.